# how do python capture 302 redirect url

Tags: python, url, redirect, capture

i try to fetch data from web,but the page use a 302 redirect
how can i use python to fetch the real url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [chapter 11.7. Handling redirects](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html) from the [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) series. It explains your entire issue in quite a bit of detail, example code and all.

Answer (score 4):

What are you currently using? Both `urllib` and `urllib2` should handle it automatically:

```
page = urllib.urlopen('http://mrozekma.com/302test.php')
>>> print page.geturl()   # This will show the redirected-to URL
http://mrozekma.com/302test.php?success
>>> print page.readlines()
['Success']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the http.client.HTTPConnection(3.x), or httplib.HTTPConnection(2.x), just obtain the Location Header:

```
response.getheader('Location')
```

I know this works at least on craigslist.org