# Python urllib - unable to authenticate automatically and receiving 302 error on NASA server

Tags: python, authentication, request, urllib

I use NASA GSFC server to retrieve data from their archives.
I send request and receives response as a simple text.

I discovered that they amended their page so that login is required.
However, even after logging I'm receiving an error.

I read information provided in thread [how do python capture 302 redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887593/how-do-python-capture-302-redirect-url)
as well as tried to use urllib2 and request libraries, but still receiving an error.

Currently part of my code responsible for downloading data looks as follows:

```
def getSampleData():
    import urllib
    # I approved application according to:
    # http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/registration/authorizing-gesdisc-data-access-in-earthdata_login
    # Query: http://hydro1.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/dods/_expr_{GLDAS_NOAH025SUBP_3H}{ave(rainf,time=00Z23Oct2016,time=00Z24Oct2016)}{17.00:25.25,48.75:54.50,1:1,00Z23Oct2016:00Z23Oct2016}.ascii?result
    sample_query = 'http://hydro1.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/dods/_expr_%7BGLDAS_NOAH025SUBP_3H%7D%7Bave(rainf,time=00Z23Oct2016,time=00Z24Oct2016)%7D%7B17.00:25.25,48.75:54.50,1:1,00Z23Oct2016:00Z23Oct2016%7D.ascii?result'

    # I've tried also:
    # sock=urllib.urlopen(sample_query, urllib.urlencode({'username':'MyUserName','password':'MyPassword'}))
    # but I was still asked to provide credentials, so I simplified mentioned line to just:
    sock=urllib.urlopen(sample_query)
    print('\n\nCurrent url:\n')
    print(sock.geturl())
    print('\nIs it the same as sample query?')
    print(sock.geturl() == sample_query)
    returnedData=sock.read()
    # returnedData always stores simple page with 302. Why? StackOverflow suggests that urllib and urllib2 handle redirection automatically
    sock.close()

    with open("Output.html", "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(returnedData)
```

[image: result page with 302 error]

Output.html content is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/oauth/authorize/?scope=uid&amp;app_type=401&amp;client_id=e2WVk8Pw6weeLUKZYOxvTQ&amp;response_type=code&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov%2Fdata-redirect&amp;state=aHR0cDovL2h5ZHJvMS5zY2kuZ3NmYy5uYXNhLmdvdi9kb2RzL19leHByXyU3QkdMREFTX05PQUgwMjVTVUJQXzNIJTdEJTdCYXZlKHJhaW5mLHRpbWU9MDBaMjNPY3QyMDE2LHRpbWU9MDBaMjRPY3QyMDE2KSU3RCU3QjE3LjAwOjI1LjI1LDQ4Ljc1OjU0LjUwLDE6MSwwMFoyM09jdDIwMTY6MDBaMjNPY3QyMDE2JTdELmFzY2lpP3Jlc3VsdA">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

If I copy-paste sample_query (sample_query from function defined above) to browser, I have no problem with receiving data.
Thus, if there's no hope for solution, I'm thinking about rewriting my code to use Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i figured out how to download data:
[How to authenticate on NASA gsfc server](https://gist.github.com/kedziorm/619141108839f154a8ded009d9cb30e8)

However, I don't know how to process dataset.
I would like to display (or write to textfile) output as a raw data (in exactly the same way as I see them in browser)